# Source or dot operator overriding execute permission?

Tags: command-line, bash

If I have turned off execute permissions on `hello.sh` and try to execute it

```
~$ sudo chmod 0666 hello.sh
~$ ./hello.sh
-bash: ./hello.sh: Permission denied
```

I get the permission error.  But I can easily override that by using the `.` or `source` builtin.

```
$ . hello.sh
hello everyone
```

What's the purpose of setting the execute permission on a file if someone can override it using the `source` builtin?

**hello.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello everyone'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference: if you execute the script like `./script.sh`, you are creating a new process, a new instance of the bash shell. This is denied.

However, since the permissions allow you to *read* the script, what's there to stop you from copy and paste all it contents? The `source` build-in does only that: it executes the commands one by one by reading them from a text file.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `./hello.sh`, you tell the *kernel* to execute the program `hello.sh`. If you have execution permission, then the kernel reads the first few bytes of the file, sees the #! line so it knows that this is a script, and runs the interpreter (`/bin/bash`), passing it the script name as its first argument. Then bash treats the file as a series of instructions. If you don't have execute permission, the kernel aborts the execution at the first step.

When you run `. hello.sh` or `source hello.sh`, you aren't asking the kernel to execute `hello.sh`. You're asking bash to read the file `hello.sh` and interpret it as a series of instructions.

It's the same thing if you run `bash hello.sh`, by the way: you aren't executing `hello.sh`, you're having it interpreted by bash (which is being executed). See [Executing a script in zsh - file permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46767/executing-a-script-in-zsh-file-permissions).